# OpenMP deal with many files

Tags: file, file-io, openmp

I've write a program which compute a calculation  in parallel with openMP on data from on a file,

let says :

```
./foobar input.txt
```

I'm on the way to modify my program such a way that, It's will do the same calculation but upon many files :

```
./foobar input1.txt input2.txt input3.txt
```

My question is :

what is suppose to be the more efficient between : 
ready each file (which can reach hundred MegaByte in size) and do a calculation in parallel on each of them,

```
for (i = O; i < numberOfFile; i++)
  calculationOn(filename[i]); // the calculation program run in parallel
```

or let each thread read in parallel it own file and work on it ?

```
#pragma omp parallel for private(i)
for(i = 0; i < numberOfFile; i++)
  calculationOn(filename[i]);
```

thanks for any reply !

Comment: This is impossible to answer without knowing what kind of algorithm you're going to apply. However, reading in datasets that don't fit in memory is surely inefficient, so try to prevent that.

Comment: @larsmans the foobar read all number in the file (which represent a matrix) and look for the maximum SubArray. I think that It's a memory Bound program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have very many files and the output per file is independent of all the other files, then you don't need OpenMP at all. Just run entire the program in parallel on multiple processors with a tool like [GNU Parallel](http://www.gnu.org/s/parallel/) to get linear speedup. An OpenMP loop over the arguments is likely quite wasteful in these cases; in terms of programmer time, that is.

Comment: hopefully no! the output of each file is independant

Comment: @FOPALéonConstantin: then don't use OpenMP, just distribute the files over multiple nodes and hope your OS's scheduler is configured correctly.